# Copy file that is being used by another process

Tags: c++, c, windows, file, file-io

I would like to clone and use a file that is being opened/used by another process. Is this actually impossible at all ?

I would like to copy the file content perhaps periodically (i.e 5 minutes per copy and use the copy in my program)

Comment: Can you tag the OS you are using, as this will make a difference.

Comment: You have tagger c, c++, file, file-io, none of these things in particular is a locking mechanism...

Comment: Are you even looking to do this pragmatically or just at all (ie over the command line)? This question might be on the wrong SE forum.

Answer (score 1):

If the other process only opened the file for reading, it should be possible; however, if it opened it for reading and writing (or just writing), then it will have locked the file so that other processes (including yours) cannot open it. At least that's the case in Windows.

Comment: That depends on your OS, so you should qualify your answer